# What dose this code means to get the name of the property of an object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties

```
#define propertyKeyPath(property)(@""＃property)
```

if I use this macro like this:

```
NSLog(@"%@",propertyKeyPath(self.someProperty));
```

I will get `self.someProperty`.

I want to know how it works,Thanks.

here is the wedsite where I see this kind of use ：“http://www.g8production.com/post/78429904103/get-property-name-as-string-without-using-the”

Comment: To the best of my knowledge `propertyKeyPath` is not a system function in iOS/Objective-C. The syntax suggests that it's a C function. Is this code that uses some third party library?

Since It isn't a normal function, I don't know what it's supposed to do, or how it's supposed to do it.

In other words I can't tell what you're talking about. 

Do you mean the NSObject method `valueForKeyPath' instead?

Comment: sorry , the code missed one "#".It's \#define propertyKeyPath(property)(@""\#property)

Comment: I see the use of this at this website, "http://www.g8production.com/post/78429904103/get-property-name-as-string-without-using-the".

Comment: If you want to add additional missing lines to the question, always use the [EDIT button](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31128080/edit).

Comment: So edit your post to show what you are talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your correction:

```
#define propertyKeyPath(property)(@""#property)
```

what this macro is doing is converting its argument to a string.

Macros work by *textual expansion* - their expansion is inserted into the text the compiler sees, the compiler then analyses the result. In a macro preceding on argument with `#` inserts the argument as a C string into the macro's expansion. So your macro call:

```
propertyKeyPath(self.someProperty)
```

is expanded to:

```
(@"""self.someProperty")
```

Now two adjacent C strings in the source are concatenated by the compiler (this is generally used as a way to break up large strings for ease of typing & reading). The expansions has two adjacent strings: `""` and `"self.someProperty"` so these are concatenated producing just `"self.someProperty"` and your text now looks like:

```
(@"self.someProperty")
```

which is compiled as an Objective-C string literal.

So that is what it does, as to *why* a macro was used rather than just writing the string literal directly I cannot say.

HTH

Comment: One possibility is that you would get code completion writing `propertyKeyPath(self.someProperty)` where you wouldn't writing out the literal string. Maybe somebody thought that was worthwhile.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - First thing I thought of as well but it didn't work, I was testing in Xcode 5. Just tried it in Xcode 6 and code completion does work. So it can provide a benefit. Thanks.